# Creating Azure monitor alert rule using REST API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

I am trying to create an Azure monitor alert rule using REST API.

Using this link to exercise the same: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alert-rules/create-or-update?view=rest-monitor-2016-03-01

Upon doing the same i am getting error like below:

```
{
  "code": "UnsupportedRequestContent",
  "message": "Request content is not well formed or supported."
}
```

Payload is as follows:

```
{
 "location": "westus",
 "properties": {
  "description": "Test Alert",
  "isEnabled": "true",
  "severity": 2,
  "evaluationFrequency": "PT1M",
  "windowSize": "PT5M",
  "condition": {
   "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria",
   "allOf": [
    {
     "name": "metric1",
     "metricNamespace": "Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts",
     "metricName": "TokenTransaction",
     "operator": "GreaterThan",
     "threshold": 50000,
     "timeAggregation": "Average",
     "dimensions": [
       {
         "name": "FeatureName",
         "operator": "Include",
         "values": [
           "gpt-4"
         ]
       }
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  "actions": [],
  "scopes": [
  "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/tgname/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/openainame"
  ]
 }
}
```

Other details:

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subid/resourcegroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Insights/alertrules/rulename?api-version=2016-03-01
Authorization: Bearer Token
Content-type: application/json
```

I dont find any microsoft documents to explain the right payload data, Any sample data to create Metric rule is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran below API call with your request body in my environment, I too got **same error**:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subid/resourcegroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Insights/alertrules/rulename?api-version=2016-03-01

{
 "location": "westus",
 "properties": {
  "description": "Test Alert",
  "isEnabled": "true",
  "severity": 2,
  "evaluationFrequency": "PT1M",
  "windowSize": "PT5M",
  "condition": {
   "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria",
   "allOf": [
    {
     "name": "metric1",
     "metricNamespace": "Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts",
     "metricName": "TokenTransaction",
     "operator": "GreaterThan",
     "threshold": 50000,
     "timeAggregation": "Average",
     "dimensions": [
       {
         "name": "FeatureName",
         "operator": "Include",
         "values": [
           "gpt-4"
         ]
       }
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  "actions": [],
  "scopes": [
  "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/tgname/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/openainame"
  ]
 }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, make use of below API call with ***modified*** request body like this:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subId/resourcegroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts/demorule2901?api-version=2018-03-01

{
  "location": "global",
  "tags": {},
  "properties": {
    "description": "Test Alert",
    "severity": 2,
    "enabled": true,
    "scopes": [
      "/subscriptions/subId/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/demoOpenAI2901"
    ],
    "evaluationFrequency": "PT1M",
    "windowSize": "PT5M",
    "criteria": {
      "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria",
      "allOf": [
        {
          "criterionType": "StaticThresholdCriterion",
          "name": "metric1",
          "metricName": "TokenTransaction",
          "dimensions": [
                {
                "name": "FeatureName",
                "operator": "Include",
                "values": [
                "gpt-4"
            ]
            }
          ],
          "operator": "GreaterThan",
          "threshold": 50000,
          "timeAggregation": "Average"
        }
      ]
    },
    "actions": []
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where **alert rule** created successfully for Azure OpenAI account scope like this:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Metric Alerts - Create Or Update - REST API (Azure Monitor) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metric-alerts/create-or-update?view=rest-monitor-2018-03-01&tabs=HTTP#create-or-update-an-alert-rule-for-single-resource)